# Cleanup broken SSH processes

Tags: 16.04, ssh, docker

I have a few weird looking processes in my docker container.

```
root      1366  0.0  0.0  18208   460 ?        Ss+  Mar08   0:00 bash
root      2103  0.0  0.0  18208   452 ?        Ss+  Mar08   0:00 bash
root      3094  0.0  0.0  18208   448 ?        Ss+  Mar08   0:00 bash
root     10078  0.0  0.0  18212   460 ?        Ss+  Mar08   0:00 bash
root     11535  0.0  0.0  18212   620 ?        Ss+  Mar08   0:00 bash
root     22641  0.0  0.0  18208  1992 ?        Ss   11:54   0:00 bash
```

I normally SSH into my server and then do a `docker exec -it my-container bash`. This sometimes hangs resulting in me having to close the terminal window.

I'm guessing the list of bash processes there is a result of my connection breaking which results in them hanging on the server.

Is there a way to detect these and remove them? Or do I have to do it manually?

Answer (score 0):

Usually ssh sessions are closed after timeout(via inactivity).
This is options in /etc/ssh/sshd_config :

```
#Default values
TCPKeepAlive yes
ClientAliveInterval 0
ClientAliveCountMax 3
```

So you don't need to worry about it.